Azure Deployment Failure: Django Azure Web App
I'm running a Django Web App - it's working locally, and was deploying successfully to Azure.
I'm now seeing the following error on the logstream:
Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640875058Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640878658Z     worker.init_process()
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640881958Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640885158Z     self.load_wsgi()
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640899358Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640909259Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640912259Z                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640915159Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640918359Z     self.callable = self.load()
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640921359Z                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640924259Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640927359Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640930759Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640933659Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640936759Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640939659Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640942759Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640945959Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640948959Z           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640952059Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.8/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640955059Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640957959Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640960859Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640964759Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640967959Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640971159Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640974259Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640977359Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640980360Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-05-03T06:02:12.640984160Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trplbackend'

This is my start up command:
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 trplbackend.wsgi:application
My project structure seems to be correct on inspection. Running this command locally also works.
I have inspected docker logs and tried re-deployment, although, nothing seems to be working. For context, in the past, my Azure Web App deployment has also been flaky.
Simply redeploying through Azure Pipelines with no changes seem to have worked.
Any ideas on how I can investigate or fix this error and make the deployment more robust?
Thank you.

if possible, can you share your github repo ?

I tried deploying a Django App to azure app service successfully without any issues.
To avoid the error message you're encountering:

Ensure that the virtual environment, where your Django project dependencies are installed, is properly configured and activated during deployment.
Make sure that the trplbackend module exists within your project structure and is accessible. Issues can arise from incorrect paths or misconfigured module names.

This is my project structure:
project_root/
├── myapp/        
├── trplbackend/   
├── venv/          
├── manage.py      
├── Procfile       
└── requirements.txt 


Procfile:
web: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 trplbackend.wsgi:application

Settings .py:
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = 'your secretkey'
DEBUG = Tru
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

MIDDLEWARE = [  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'trplbackend.urls
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors':[              
'django.template.context_processors.debug',               'django.template.context_processors.request',               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'trplbackend.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

Run the below command, this will list all the Python dependencies required by your project
pip freeze > requirements.txt

local output:

I Deployed Django app via visual studio code extension and it was successful without any issues


Log stream:

Here's the output:

